# dig returns SERVFAIL but +trace works

Tags: dns, bind

Here is the main problem:

```
dig maktabkhooneh.info +trace
```

works perfectly fine and returns the right answer.

```
dig maktabkhooneh.info
```

(without +trace) returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> maktabkhooneh.info

;; global options: +cmd

;; Got answer:

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 58716

;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

What could be the reason? I was reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/65499/dig-trace-resolves-while-without-doesnt). Is it the only possible reason that I changed domain data 12hrs ago? Isn't there any other possible reason for `SERVFAIL`?

**extra info:**

I have two BIND servers working on 168.144.251.73 (master) and 168.144.92.50 (slave).

and on the master I have:

```
$TTL 300

maktabkhooneh.info.        IN    SOA     ns1.maktabkhooneh.info.   
admin.maktabkhooneh.info. (

2012060201    ; Serial

86400    ; Refresh

7200     ; Retry

3600000    ; Expire

300 )  ; Minimum


maktabkhooneh.info.        IN    A       168.144.97.83

maktabkhooneh.info.        IN    NS      ns1.maktabkhooneh.info.

maktabkhooneh.info.        IN        NS      ns2.maktabkhooneh.info.

ns1     IN    A   168.144.251.73

ns2     IN    A   168.144.92.50

www     IN    CNAME   maktabkhooneh.info.
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`dig +trace` follows the whole chain from the beginning - it queries root servers, then .info servers then your namservers. Thus it avoids any caching resolvers, and also avoids propagation issues.

`dig +notrace` (the default) queries your default DNS resolver (on Linux, whatever specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`).

There's some problem with that resolver - maybe it's misconfigured, maybe it has old data in its caches, maybe it can not reach your authoritative nameservers, etc.

Comment: This can also happen due to misconfigured DNSSEC

Comment: or DNSSEC Key re-signing problem

Comment: Hoe can I fix it, if the problem is old data cache? I have to edit manually and remove the old data?

Answer (score 0):

In my case was a problem related to /etc/named.conf file. I could resolve this with the previous answer from Sandman and googling the way to fix a corrupted named.conf in cpanel. I had to access to shell console and type the following commands:

for backup the file

```
mv /etc/named.conf /etc/named.conf.bak
```

for rebuild the file

```
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/rebuilddnsconfig
```

for restart the named service

```
/etc/init.d/named restart
```

ref: https://www.web24.com.au/tutorials/named-conf-fix-corrupted-named-conf-cpanel